# Bones/Armature do not show up once I change the view

Tags: animation, armature

I am very new to Blender and I am attempting to create a humanoid for a gaming program. Currently, I am trying to animate my character and I have my armature set up on the front of my humanoid. Unfortunately, if I try to change the view of my humanoid, the bones disappear immediately. How do I fix this?

[This is the first view with the bones displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7TSx.png)

[The bones completely disappear when I change the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X01kw.png)

Comment: are you sure that the armature is not far away on the right or on the left? Try an alt G to see if it doesn't come back to the center...

Comment: Ahh I'm such an idiot. Looks like the bones were just really far away lol. Thank you so much!